# How to fix INVALID REQUEST error when sending POST request with python requests library?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to send a POST request via python using the built in requests library, I got the request through Burpsuite and I am now trying to convert the POST request to python code, this is what i have written up so far:

```
import requests
CreateAndStartHeaders = {
    "Host": "germany-rental.taxify.eu",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": "166",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "Basic KzQ5MTc2NzA4Njc1MDQ6MUZCRjAwMEYtQkQzRC00RjgwLUE5NUItRUZFODg4RjYzQzVB",
    "User-Agent": "Bolt/109764413 CFNetwork/1390 Darwin/22.0.0",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    }

data = {
    "vehicle_handle" : {
    "value" : "333-333",
    "type" : "uuid"
  },
  
  "source" : "single_order",
  "payment_instrument_id" : "adyen_paypal\/6216325090316059"
    }

url = "https://germany-rental.taxify.eu/micromobility/user/ui/order/createAndStart?gps_age=0.4934508800506592&signup_session_id=e17333a3083993252554877ff58328094ffc3e225168026c4ed412a6518e8f47&country=de&lat=50.09257534411632&user_id=90791700&gps_lat=50.09243612776929&version=CI.91.0&device_name=iPhone12,8&gps_lng=8.225763438023886&lng=8.225648382329815&deviceType=iphone&distinct_id=client-90791700&rh_session_id=90791700u1684582741&language=en-GB&gps_accuracy_m=9.485426861614163&deviceId=ABD8E483-E0A1-496F-826E-6E96A2677BA8&device_os_version=iOS16.0&session_id=90791700u1684583212"
r = requests.post(url, headers=CreateAndStartHeaders,data=data)
print(r.content)
```

I get the error code `code":702,"message":"INVALID_REQUEST` what am I doing wrong here?

I tried reformatting the data and body part but both didnt work Im pretty new to requests and a bit lost right now

Answer (score 1):

I solved it turns out the data I was sending in the request body has to be correctly formatted to JSON. The data variable in my code is a dictionary, so you I can use the `json` parameter instead of `data` to automatically convert it to JSON.
So in order to fix the problem all I had to do was replace the post request line with this updated code snippet:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=CreateAndStartHeaders, json=data)
```